# golang: сравнение заявленного типа данных из строки json с полученным по факту

Tags: golang

На вход *s* получаю json с заявленными, в том числе, типами данных: int32, int64, undefined.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    s := `{"abc":{"a": [["xyz", 1000, 1663676406222, -0.0087, null]]}}`
    // заявленный тип:    ^string ^_int32 ^_int64     ^_double ^_undefined
    var f map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &f); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) //
    }

    f1 := f["abc"].(map[string]interface{})
    f2 := f1["a"].([]interface{})
    d3 := []string{}
    d4 := []string{}
    for h := range f2 {
        for x := range f2[h].([]interface{}) {
            v := f2[h].([]interface{})[x]

            switch castedV := v.(type) {

            case string:
                d3 = append(d3, castedV) // castedV - строка
                d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(castedV).String())
            case int:
                d3 = append(d3, strconv.Itoa(castedV)) // castedV - число int
                d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(castedV).String())
            case float64:
                d3 = append(d3, strconv.FormatFloat(castedV, 'E', -1, 64)) // castedV - число float64
                d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(castedV).String())
            default:
                d3 = append(d3, fmt.Sprint(v))
                d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(fmt.Sprint(v)).String())
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("d3 = ", d3) // [xyz 1E+03 1.663676406222E+12 -8.7E-03 <nil>]
    fmt.Println("d4 = ", d4) // [string float64 float64 float64 string]
    // - - -
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(1000))               // int
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(1e+03))              // float64
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(1663676406222))      // int
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(1.663676406222e+12)) // float64
}
```

Надо проверить, что заявленный тип данных, указанный в комментарии к коду, соответствует полученным. Как сделать, чтобы получить на выходе приведенное ниже?

```
 d3 = ["xyz", "1000", "1663676406222", "-0.0087", "null"]
 d4 = ["string", "int", "int", "float64", "undefined"]
```

Comment: в JSON нет целых чисел. Любое число, даже если он выглядит как целое, является числом с плавающей точкой. Вы сами это видите в `d4`. Поэтому вам нужно самостоятельно распознавать целые числа.

Comment: @Pak Uula, `самостоятельно распознавать целые числа` программно или визуально?  первое не получается, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `encoding/json` есть потоковый декодер. У этого декодера есть режим распознавания чисел в тип `json.Number`, который внутри себя не более чем `string`. Остаётся только понять, что за число внутри этого `string`:

```
func ToInt32(jn json.Number) (int32, bool) {
    s := string(jn)
    n, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 32)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, false
    }
    s2 := strconv.FormatInt(n, 10)
    if s == s2 {
        return int32(n), true
    } else {
        return 0, false
    }
}

func ToInt64(jn json.Number) (int64, bool) {
    s := string(jn)
    n, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, false
    }
    s2 := strconv.FormatInt(n, 10)
    if s == s2 {
        return n, true
    } else {
        return 0, false
    }
}

func ToFloat64(jn json.Number) (float64, bool) {
    s := string(jn)
    f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return 0.0, false
    }
    return f, true
}
```

Тогда ваш `switch` можно переписать вот как:

```
func main() {

    s := `{"abc":{"a": [["xyz", 1000, 1663676406222, -0.0087, null]]}}`
    // заявленный тип:    ^string ^_int32 ^_int64     ^_double ^_undefined
    var f map[string]interface{}

    stream := strings.NewReader(s)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(stream)
    decoder.UseNumber()
    if err := decoder.Decode(&f); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    f1 := f["abc"].(map[string]interface{})
    f2 := f1["a"].([]interface{})
    d3 := []string{}
    d4 := []string{}
    for h := range f2 {
        for x := range f2[h].([]interface{}) {
            v := f2[h].([]interface{})[x]

            switch castedV := v.(type) {

            case string:
                d3 = append(d3, castedV) // castedV - строка
                d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(castedV).String())
            case int:
                d3 = append(d3, strconv.Itoa(castedV)) // castedV - число int
                d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(castedV).String())
            case float64:
                d3 = append(d3, strconv.FormatFloat(castedV, 'E', -1, 64)) // castedV - число float64
                d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(castedV).String())
            case json.Number:
                // castedV - число json.Number
                if i, ok := ToInt32(castedV); ok {
                    d3 = append(d3, castedV.String())
                    d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(i).String())
                } else if i64, ok := ToInt64(castedV); ok {
                    d3 = append(d3, castedV.String())
                    d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(i64).String())
                } else if f, ok := ToFloat64(castedV); ok {
                    d3 = append(d3, castedV.String())
                    d4 = append(d4, reflect.TypeOf(f).String())
                } else {
                    d3 = append(d3, castedV.String())
                    d4 = append(d4, "Хрен знает что")
                }
            default:
                t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
                var tStr string
                if t == nil {
                    d3 = append(d3, "nil")
                    tStr = "nil"
                } else {
                    d3 = append(d3, fmt.Sprint(v))
                    tStr = t.String()
                }
                d4 = append(d4, tStr)
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("d3 = ", d3) // [xyz 1E+03 1.663676406222E+12 -8.7E-03 <nil>]
    fmt.Println("d4 = ", d4) // [string float64 float64 float64 string]
}
```

Полный пример https://go.dev/play/p/Uo9Ex82FgmZ

```
d3 =  [xyz 1000 1663676406222 -0.0087 nil]
d4 =  [string int32 int64 float64 nil]
```